# Prolog Call, Exit and Redo not matching specified rules

Tags: prolog, rules

I was having some problem trying to trace the prolog. The trace log as follow:

```
parent_of(X,Y).
Call: (6) parent_of(_G2780, _G2781) ? creep
Exit: (6) parent_of(warren, jerry) ? creep
X = warren
Y = jerry ;
Redo: (6) parent_of(_G2780, _G2781) ? creep
Exit: (6) parent_of(maryalice, jerry) ? creep
X = maryalice
Y = jerry ;
Redo: (6) parent_of(_G2780, _G2781) ? creep
Call: (7) brother(_G2865, _G2781) ? creep
Exit: (7) brother(jerry, kather) ? creep
Call: (7) father(_G2780, jerry) ? creep
Call: (8) parent_of(_G2780, jerry) ? creep
Exit: (8) parent_of(warren, jerry) ? creep
Call: (8) male(warren) ? creep
Exit: (8) male(warren) ? creep
Exit: (7) father(warren, jerry) ? creep
Exit: (6) parent_of(warren, kather) ? creep
```

However, I declared my facts and rules as follow:

```
male(jerry).
male(stuart).
male(warren).
male(peter).
female(kather).
female(maryalice).
female(ann)
brother(jerry,stuart).
brother(jerry,kather).
brother(peter, warren).
sister(ann, maryalice).
sister(kather,jerry).
parent_of(warren,jerry).
parent_of(maryalice,jerry).

parent_of(X,Z):- brother(Y,Z),(father(X,Y);mother(X,Y)).
father(X,Y) :-  parent_of(X,Y), male(X).
mother(X,Y) :-  parent_of(X,Y), female(X).
```

I thought the first Call by right should execute brother and (father and mother)? How come it straight away gave me the Exit which is Warren is the parent of Jerry?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a syntax error. You need a period after `female(ann)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog finds facts and rules in the order they are asserted. Since you have some facts `parent_of/2` asserted before your rule `parent_of/2`, those are found first. You didn't show your full trace, but after it finds the facts, it traces into the rule:

```
[trace]  ?- parent_of(X,Y).
   Call: (7) parent_of(_G1353, _G1354) ? creep
   Exit: (7) parent_of(warren, jerry) ? creep
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
   Redo: (7) parent_of(_G1353, _G1354) ? creep
   Exit: (7) parent_of(maryalice, jerry) ? creep
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
   Redo: (7) parent_of(_G1353, _G1354) ? creep
   Call: (8) brother(_G1444, _G1354) ? creep
   Exit: (8) brother(jerry, stuart) ? creep
   Call: (8) father(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent_of(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent_of(warren, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (9) male(warren) ? creep
   Exit: (9) male(warren) ? creep
   Exit: (8) father(warren, jerry) ? creep
   Exit: (7) parent_of(warren, stuart) ? creep
X = warren,
Y = stuart ;
   Redo: (9) parent_of(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent_of(maryalice, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (9) male(maryalice) ? creep
   Fail: (9) male(maryalice) ? creep
   Redo: (9) parent_of(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (10) brother(_G1444, jerry) ? creep
   Fail: (10) brother(_G1444, jerry) ? creep
   Fail: (9) parent_of(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Fail: (8) father(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Redo: (7) parent_of(_G1353, stuart) ? creep
   Call: (8) mother(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent_of(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent_of(warren, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (9) female(warren) ? creep
   Fail: (9) female(warren) ? creep
   Redo: (9) parent_of(_G1353, jerry) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent_of(maryalice, jerry) ? creep
   Call: (9) female(maryalice) ? creep
   Exit: (9) female(maryalice) ? creep
   Exit: (8) mother(maryalice, jerry) ? creep
   Exit: (7) parent_of(maryalice, stuart) ? creep
X = maryalice,
Y = stuart
...
```

I would recommend, however, that you make your rule names different than fact names. So I would do something like:

```
parent(warren,jerry).
parent(maryalice,jerry).
```

Then:

```
parent_of(X,Z) :-
    parent(X, Z).
parent_of(X,Z) :-
    brother(Y,Z),
    ( father(X,Y); mother(X,Y) ).
```

But also be careful of redundant facts. It looks like your parent relationships might already be defined by facts involving `father/2` and `mother/2`. So it's unclear why you need the `parent/2` facts at all.

NOTE that your code has a syntax error here:

```
female(ann)
brother(jerry,stuart).
```

You probably ignored the error. But without the period, Prolog will ignore the above two facts, and then give you the results you are seeing.

---

On another note, your code has a lot of circular logic which is not good. `parent_of/2` depends upon `father/2` and `mother/2` and then `father/2` and `mother/2` call `parent_of/2`. This is another critical reason to separate the facts from the predicates.

Comment: I see but after the X = maryalice Y = jerry ; right, for the third one I get X = warren Y = kather. I not sure why it skipped stuart since the facts for brother(jerry, stuart) was declared before kather. Let me update the trace log.

Comment: @Fyndy your first to facts are for `warren` & `jerry` and for `maryalice` & `jerry`, and it found those two first, in order, as expected. The next one it found is `warren`  & `stuart` using the rule. I don't know what you mean when you say "it skipped stuart". See my trace. I ran your code directly. So if you are getting `warren` & `kather` for your third solution, you are not running the code you posted.

Comment: I tried to trace it by reading it as 2780 is the parent of 2781. 2865 is the brother of 2781. But then at the Exit there, how am I supposed to know 2865 is jerry and 2781 is kather? I updated my trace log and I reran for a couple of times already and I am still getting kather.

Comment: @Fyndy those numbers just correspond to anonymous variable names, which are just variables until they are instantiated. So the numbers *do not* directly correspond to your atoms. They are just arbitrary numbers for the variables to distinguish them. What Prolog are you using? SWI? Something else? And what version? I ran the code exactly as you show in your question in SWI and I get the results I show in my answer. So double check that's what you are actually using for your code.

Comment: @Fyndy I think I may know the problem. You have a syntax error where you left the period off of `female(ann)`. As a result, Prolog did not recognize that fact, nor the following fact, `brother(jerry,stuart).`. I had fixed that error when I ran your code, so I didn't observe the same results you did.

Comment: @luker I see yeah that's the syntax problem. I not getting the stuart already. But may I know that after running the third solution right, if I were to find the 4th solution, I got a Redo: (8) parent_of(_G2780, jerry) Exit: (8) parent_of(maryalice, jerry) Call: (8) male(maryalice). May I know why the 4th solution start from the father(X,Y) rule?

Comment: @Fyndy I filled in the trace for the 4th solution. Your code has a lot of circular logic (see my added comment in the answer), so you need to determine which `father/2` and `parent_of/2` are being called. If you look at the numbers in parentheses in the trace, they show you the reference back to where it backtracks. The only `father/2` I see in the trace for the 4th solution is a failure from a backtrack referencing (8), which means it was still finding possible solutions to `father(_G1353, jerry)`.

Comment: I see I see. Thanks so much for the clarification. I guess it's the time for me to reconstruct the code :)